# How can I put the shine back on my wood floor - just one spot.

Tags: wood, flooring

I used a Mr.Clean Scrubber on my wood floor to remove a black heel mark.  It took the shine off the floor.  It is a small spot and I would like to somehow put something on it to mask the dullness.  The flooring is real wood that came prefinished in the box. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried floor paste wax?